# sed: replacing text if the next line does not start with }

Tags: replace, sed

I would like to replace ; with , if the next line does not start with } and if the next line is not empty.

if next line starts with } or it is empty then ; must be removed.

for example

```
struct Point {
    float x;   
    float y;
};
```

should be changed like below

```
type something{
type record Point{
 c_float x,
 c_float y
};
}
```

All other changes via sed are working except this ';' to ',' and i really does not have anymore ideas how to continue with this.. :(

Answer (score 1):

With awk instead of sed:

```
echo 'struct Point {
    float x;
    float y;
};' |
awk '
    $1 == "};" {
        print prev
        print
        print "}"
        in_struct = 0
    }
    in_struct {
        if (prev) {print prev ","}
        prev = $0
        sub(/; *$/, "", prev)
        sub(/float/, "c_&", prev)
    }
    $1 == "struct" {
        print "type something {"
        $1 = "type record"
        print
        prev = ""
        in_struct = 1
    }
'
```

outputs

```
type something {
type record Point {
    c_float x,
    c_float y
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[DoD@MBP-13~/temp] cat file
struct Point {
     float x;   
     float y;
};   


[DoD@MBP-13~/temp] sed ' /^}\|^$/ s/;// ' file | sed 'N ; /}/! s/;/,/ ' | sed 'N ; /}/ s/;//'
struct Point {
    float x,   
    float y
}
```

The first sed iteration looks for lines that starts with "}" or blank lines and removes ";" and second sed iteration loads the new line into buffer checks if it does not contain "}" then substitutes ";" to ",". Third iteration looks for "}" and removes ";".

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
a="SOMETHING"
sed -r '/^struct\s*\S*\s*\{/,/^\};/s/^struct\s*(\S*)\s*\{/type '"$a"'{\ntype record \1\{/;s/^\};/&\n}/' input_file |
sed -r '/^type '"$a"'\{/,/^\}/{//b;/^type/b;/^\};/!N;/.\n/{s/\s*/&c_/;/\n(\};|$)/{s/;//;ta};{s/;/,/}};:a;P;D};P;D'
```

Owing to the nature of the problem I found it easiest to use to passes, it probably can be condensed.

BTW this was done GNU sed other sed's might not work!